# nonblocking-io vs blocking-io on raw data throughput

Tags: java, performance, io, nio

In [apache HTTPComponent document](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/tutorial/html/nio.html) there is a statement:

> Contrary to the popular belief, the performance of NIO in terms of raw data throughput is significantly lower than that of blocking I/O."

Is that true? Can someone explain this in more details? And what is a typical use case where

> request / response handling needs to be decoupled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non blocking IO should be used when you can handle the request, dispatch it for processing on some other execution context (different thread, RPC call to another server, some other async mechanism) and release the web-server's thread to handle more incoming requests. When the processing of the response will be completed, a response handling thread will be invoked, and it will send the response to the client.

I would recommend reading [netty documentation](http://www.jboss.org/netty/documentation) for better understanding of the concept.

As for higher throughput: When your server sends/recieves large amounts of data, all those context switches, and passing data between threads, can really hurt overall performance. Think of it like this: you receive a  large request (PUT request with a large file). All you need to do is to save it to disk, and return OK. Starting to toss it between threads could result in few more mem-copy operations that would have been needed in case you've just threw it to disk in the same thread. And handling this operation in async manner would not improve performance: though you could have released the request handling thread back to web-server's thread pool and let it process other requests, your main performance bottleneck is your disk IO, and in this case - trying to save more files simultaneously, would only make things slower.

I hope I was clear enough. Please feel free to ask more questions in comments if you need more explanations.

Comment: So can I make the conclusion that the most advantage that non-blocking io provide is Capacity, i.e. the amount of simutaneous requests that can be dealed with per server, not total Throughput or Speed per request-processing ? If I add more servers in the cluster, can I achieve the same result with better speed and throughputs using blocking io, provided that my application architecture has good horizontal scalability?

Comment: Roughly - yes. Of course all your server use some shared resource (database, shared file-system, some back-end service) you would be constrained by it's speed, but if you don't have anything of the sort, adding more servers will get you better throughput in most cases. Also programming asynchronously is harder and much more error prone.

Comment: On the other hand, adding more servers to the cluster, is expansive, and probably will not help you to cope with massive amount of small requests that require almost no server time (For example web server which uses non-blocking IO is much more resilient to DOS attacks - it responds with the proper error code to the attackers, and does what it needs to do for valid requests)

Comment: Get it. Thank you for the elaborate answer.

Answer (score 3):

The first statement is true only when the number of concurrent requests is relatively small (rather in tens than thousands). It's all about using many threads (blocking) instead of one or few threads (non-blocking). Let's say you want to write an application which only downloads a file from remote server. If your application need to download only one file at a time you need only one thread. But if you have a crawler which runs thousands of HTTP requests then you need to have thousands of threads (or use limited number of threads + NIO instead). For so big number of threads the problem is context switching which can slow down your application dramatically (therefore for this number of concurrent requests NIO is better).

But let's back to your question. Why NIO can be slower in terms of raw data throughput ? The reason is the amount of CPU time used by NIO driven applications. For such case in blocking model your code is doing only one thing - waiting for data (it executes recv() operation in a loop). In the NIO application the logic is much more complicated: in a loop the code is using the selector to select a set of keys (which involves epoll_wait system call on Linux, Oracle JVM), then iterate through the set, pick up a channel for every key and then read the data from the channel (read() operation in OS). In standard blocking model all you do is to execute the recv() system function. In summary: NIO driven application in such case use more CPU time and generates more mode switch operations because of higher number of system calls (by saying mode switch I mean the switch from user to kernel mode). Therefore the time needed to download the file will be higher.

Comment: But if almost all the threads are blocked waiting for I/O then there's no context switching going on, I thought ... so is context switching costs really the issue with using threads for many concurrent requests?

Comment: @DobesVandermeer the OS scheduler has to spend resources on idle threads anyway, to control whether they need to be woken up. So yes, idle threads have a cost, too.